# Error inflating class ImageView (not SVG)

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-inflate

On AndroidStudio 3.0.1

My app has a `RecyclerView` which to which `LinearLayout`s are inflated through a custom Adapter- `CardAdapter`. On API>=24 it works fine, but on API<24 it has a fatal error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
    at com.example.stavnoy.geronimosample.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:31)
```

(full log at bottom)

I am using a .jpg as `src` for the `ImageView`, not an SVG

This is my layout for inflation - `list_item`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:weightSum="8"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <ImageView
        style="@style/CardElement"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:src="@drawable/unavailable"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="Photo unavailable"/>
    <TextView
        style="@style/CardElement"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        style="@style/CardElement"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Ipsum Lorem" />

    <View
        android:tag="line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/CardElement"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical">
        <TextView
            style="@style/CardButton"
            android:text="@string/details_button_caps"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:onClick="details"/>
        <TextView
            style="@style/CardButton"
            android:text="@string/share_button_caps"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:onClick="share"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My CardAdapter:

```
class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private final Context context;
private final JSONArray data;

CardAdapter(final JSONArray allCardsData, final Context context) {
    this.data = allCardsData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CardViewHolder((LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false));    //line 33
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //more code
}
```

My custom styles (which include `layout_width` and `layout_height`):

```
    <style name="CardButton">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">end</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>

<style name="CardElement">
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>
```

Full log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                  at com.example.stavnoy.geronimosample.CardAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CardAdapter.java:31)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6519)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5706)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5589)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5585)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2231)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1558)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1518)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:585)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.sy
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Is the drawable a vector drawable? Or animated vector drawable?

Comment: You're too fast. I was just editing to state that no, it's a .jpg

Comment: Does it all build fine if you remove the style tag from your xml elements?

Comment: If you remove the style then `layout_width` and `layout_height` would be missing.

Comment: try moving your layout_height and width to the elements and removing them from style. In terms of how it is drawn, I believe styles are applied second hand. Which means you would not be able to draw the item as height and width are "pre -draw" requirements. Whereas text style size, font etc.. can happen post draw. It is why you are NOT allowed to bind height and width because they are pre draw items. So try moving those out of your style and you will probably be ok

Comment: @Sam To reiterate, I tried removing `style` entirely from the `ImageView` and explicitly adding `layout_width` and `layout_height` elements. This changes nothing. Additionally, if I remove the whole `ImageView` the app only fails at `onBindViewHolder()` (it relies on the ImageView)- meaning **inflation executed successfully for all the other views** utilizing the style, even if there are repeated attributes.

Comment: Hi @StavNoy can you also share your CardViewHolder class that you are returning. Lastly, if you can share the code base I'd be happy to pull it and take a look, but if it is proprietary, you would need to make a copy of just the problematic part and separate that into a project you can share. Otherwise, it's hard to help when we can't see the updates that you are making as instructed. I either need to see 100% of all code involved and the way it sits with the changes and the latest error. by involved i mean anything that is referenced in this adapter at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xavier Rubio Jansana's suggestion to use a system drawable for `src` worked, leading to the problem: bad resource management.
I was storing the .jpg files in the `drawable` directory rather than the `mipmap` directory. It works for a Layout file that is used directly, but not for `inflate()`. I still don't know why API>=24 manages to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

From the added styles, my guess would then be (assuming style is not `-v24`) that the repeated attributes may be accepted in API 24+, but not in previous versions:

```
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_weight="5"
```

I would try to remove them from the styles and move it to the elements not having them explicitly, or creating an additional style just for the `ImageView`.

Comment: Oh my! They are missing from all the views! This could be a serious bug in the SDK, unless he's setting them in the style.

Comment: I didn't realize at the beginning ;)

Comment: Then, that could explain why it's working in 24+. Are you sure the style is also applied for previous versions? Any warning message in the editor?

Comment: Don't think that's right, unless I'm misunderstanding: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html#ApplyingStyles)

Comment: Removing the style and moving to the element explicitly does not work.

Comment: The only remaining thing I can think of it looks a bit strange is `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"`. After that, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Removed  `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"`. No change. Thank's for trying.

Comment: You're welcome. What about removing the image from `android:src` (removing the tag or maybe trying to change it for a system drawable like `@android:color/black`). This, of course, is to try to pin down what's making the inflation fail. In any case, I'm curious and I would like to know the reason.